# AWS IAM policy: Multiple Actions and Multiple Resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-kms, ssm

It is question on AWS IAM policy, multiple Actions with Multiple Resources (presumably not related). I have parameter 'myparam' encrypted with 'mykey', and I have policy as below separate blocks, one for param and one for key, it works.

```
{
    {
        "Action": [
            "ssm:GetParameter",
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "MY-ARN:MY-ACC:parameter/myparam"
    },
    {
        "Action": [
            "kms:Decrypt"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "MY-ARN:MY-ACC::key/mykey"
    }
}
```

As per documentation, We can combine multiple actions and resources, If I combine the same as below, Does this work?

```
{
    {
        "Action": [
            "ssm:GetParameter",
            "kms:Decrypt"
        ],

        "Resource": [ 
            "MY-ARN:MY-ACC:parameter/myparam"
            "MY-ARN:MY-ACC::key/mykey"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow"
    }

}
```

How the Actions to Resource mapping happens in this case? I couldn't find any documentation on this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_action.html
If I have associated resources or associed Actiosn then it makes sense, What is your comments on this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> If I combine the same as below, Does this work?

**Yes** it does.

To verify that I **recreated** your scenario with `mykey` and `myparam` and an inline policy added to an execution role of a test lambda.

As a matter of fact, when you are using IAM console to create such permissions, the inline json policy created will have the **second form**, not the first one:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "ssm:GetParameter"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:kms:*:xxx:key/e15f691e-5dde-473c-8f24-3af45994aeaf",
                "arn:aws:ssm:*:xxx:parameter/myparam"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What's more the **order of items** in `Actons` to `Resources` is irrelevant. Thus you can also have (different action order):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:GetParameter",
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:kms:*:xxx:key/e15f691e-5dde-473c-8f24-3af45994aeaf",
                "arn:aws:ssm:*:xxx:parameter/myparam"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This means that IAM will test the actions to resources **only if a given resource supports** them.

The first form if often preferred, as its easier to read and manage. If you put everything into one statement, its difficult to name such a statement, edit it and debug.

Comment: @Krishna No problem. Hope it helps to clarify the issue.

Comment: Hi Marcin - Just a question: if I have parameters say myparam1 and myparam2,

In resource section, If I have below line, 
"MY-ARN:MY-ACC:parameter/myparam/*"
I believe 'getParameter' will get access to both parameters.

But what about this line,
"MY-ARN:MY-ACC:parameter/myparam*"

Will 'getParameter' get access both parameters?